# Alert box text copy issue with Chrome

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to know the way with which I can straight away copy the text in alert box, it is allowing me to copy the text in IE, Safari but not in latest chrome version. Any idea how to do the same.

Thanks

Comment: Select text, right click, copy ?  What do you mean by "straight away copy"?  How do you do it in IE?

Comment: for IE ctrl + C is working, but after the recent version of chrome, somehow Ctrl + C has stopped working on alert box

Comment: In chrome, you need to select the text first.  It's part of the browser, not something you can change with [tag:javascript] (unless you overwrite the alert function, which is not recommended).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert try using this link, click on tryit and try to copy the text it wont allow you.

Comment: Copied fine: "I am an alert box!" (ran try it, double clicked/highlighted text in alert box, ctrl-c, switch to here, add comment, ctrl-v)  Chrome: 59.0.3071.115

Comment: Whether it works or not, it's not something you'll be able to change via javascript.

Answer (score 10):

I've had this problem, as I've wanted to copy text in an alert to a translator since it was in a language I didn't read.

What I ended up doing was:

While on the page that causes the alert to appear, open Chrome's developer tools by typing (F12) or (CTRL SHIFT I) or Menu-> More Tools -> Developer tools.

Go to the developer tools console pane and, at the text entry prompt starting with `>`, type:

```
alert = ( () => {
  const oldAlert = alert;
  var inAlert = false;
  return (x) => {
    if (!inAlert) {
      console.log(x);
      inAlert = true;
      return oldAlert(x)
      inAlert=false;
    };
  }
} )()
```

That command supplements the alert functionality so that any alert message also gets written to the debug console, where it's easy to copy.  Now, do whatever you did that causes the alert to appear and dismiss it.  When you go look at that console window, you should see that it has printed the text you wanted to copy.  You can copy it from there.

Comment: This worked in that the alert text appeared in the console, but it also resulted in an infinite loop that locked up my browser. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You're right.  Fixed it to something a lot less clean looking, but that will be sure to prevent infinite loops.